# Complete tracing using zipkin-go

Tags: go, zipkin, distributed-tracing

I have some services. I want to trace those services using zipkin-go. In every service, I am calling some of my other internal services or db calls. I want to trace every activity like how much time it has taken to call internal services or db. I have implemented using available tutorials on internet. Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"os"
"net/http"
"log"
"github.com/gorilla/handlers"
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"Upload-Image-API/services/controllers/updatemodrefid"
"Upload-Image-API/services/controllers/uploadimage"
"Upload-Image-API/services/utils"
"github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-go"
"github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-go/model"
zipkinhttp "github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-go/middleware/http"
reporterhttp "github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-go/reporter/http"
)

const endpointURL = "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans"

func newTracer() (*zipkin.Tracer, error) {
   // The reporter sends traces to zipkin server
   reporter := reporterhttp.NewReporter(endpointURL)
   port := utils.GetString("serviceListeningPort")
   if port == "" {
        fmt.Println("Port is not defined in configuration ...!!!")
        os.Exit(1)
   }
   // Local endpoint represent the local service information
   localEndpoint := &model.Endpoint{ServiceName: "Upload-Image-API", Port: 7795}

   // Sampler tells you which traces are going to be sampled or not. In this case we will record 100% (1.00) of traces.
   sampler, err := zipkin.NewCountingSampler(1)
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }

   t, err := zipkin.NewTracer(
      reporter,
      zipkin.WithSampler(sampler),
      zipkin.WithLocalEndpoint(localEndpoint),
   )
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }

   return t, err
}


func main() {
    var err error
    var environment = os.Args[1]
    err = utils.LoadDefaultConfig(environment)
    tracer, err := newTracer()
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // We add the instrumented transport to the defaultClient
    // that comes with the zipkin-go library
    http.DefaultClient.Transport, err = zipkinhttp.NewTransport(
        tracer,
        zipkinhttp.TransportTrace(true),
    )
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not load the configuration because of following err " + err.Error() + " ...!!!")
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Configurations sucessfully loaded for environment " + environment + " ...!!!")
    }
    allowedHeaders := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With"})
    allowedOrigins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    allowedMethods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})

    port := utils.GetString("serviceListeningPort")
    if port == "" {
        fmt.Println("Port is not defined in configuration ...!!!")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/uploadimage", uploadimage.UploadImages).Methods("POST", "GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/updatemodrefid", updatemodrefid.UpdateModRefId).Methods("POST", "GET")
    router.Use(zipkinhttp.NewServerMiddleware(
  tracer,
  zipkinhttp.SpanName("request")), // name for request span
)
    err = http.ListenAndServe(port, handlers.CORS(allowedHeaders, allowedOrigins, allowedMethods)(router))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Count not start the server because of following err " + err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

I am getting my request traced but I am not able to trace what is happening inside the `uploadimage` controller. Below is the screenshot of my zipkin UI:

[image: Zipkin UI]

I want to trace all the activities happening inside uploadimage controller. What should I need to pass so that I can trace all.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to zipkin and golang, If you want to trace internal process, then you can create span from context

example: say you have api called Login, inside login you might perform database operation or any other operations

```
func Login(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    span, _ := tracer.StartSpanFromContext(req.Context(), "database")
    databaseOperation()
    span.Finish()
}
```